# How to fix the error AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_session'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, imageai

I get an error when executing this code
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGGk0.jpg)

Comment: Please, copy and paste the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
pip install keras==2.3.0
```

your tensorflow/keras version is too high. This command should solve your problem.

Comment: but tensorflow==1.31.1 is not actively supported i think it will get error

Comment: no, there will be no error. I'm using this version on regular basis. and the code you are using is written in tensorflow lower version. It won't work in tensorflow version 2.